# Re-render issue while using useMemo hooks

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, memoization

```
const sum = useMemo(() => a + b, [a, b])
```

What will happen when `a` and `b` are interchanged ?

Like if `a = 5`, `b = 10` in the current render. What will happen when `a = 10`, `b = 5`? Will it re-render after it is changed?

Not getting the consistent answer for this.

Comment: You have a and b as dependencies. That means that whenever either a or b changes, the function inside useMemo will be recomputed, and sum will be updated accordingly. So yes it will re-render

Comment: Add some logging and find out.

Comment: I think it also depends where `a` and `b` come from.

Comment: `useMemo` itself has nothing to do with triggerring a rerender

Comment: Are you asking whether the `a+b` computation is executed again, or whether the component re-renders? What is the actual "issue" you are experiencing?

Answer (score 2):

A re-render occurs whenever the state changes (among other things).

In your case, the value of `sum` will be recomputed if either `a` or `b` changes. However, it won't trigger a re-render of the component because it is not part of its state.

Changing the value of `a` or `b` will provoke a re-render because they are either part of the state of the component or are passed as props.

Comment: "*it won't, by itself, trigger a re-render of the component.*" - `useMemo` will **never** do that, regardless whether it did recompute the value or not, or whether the result value is the same as before or not.

Comment: I never really thought of that, but you are right useMemo will never trigger a rerender, because it is not part of the state of a component.  I willl edit my answer, thank you for pointing that out

Answer (score 0):

It’s not a matter of `useMemo()` hook, as it is created to cache result of intensive calculations.

The question here, as noticed Florent, is what is `a` and `b` – are they props variables or state variables, or some other specific case.

If it’s state or props - it will trigger re-render.

If this is special case like value of uncontrolled input or saved using `useRef()`, it will not trigger re-render.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

You are confusing rendering for computing.

> Like if `a = 5`, `b = 10` in the current render. What will happen when `a = 10`, `b = 5`? will it re-render after it is changed?

No. The `useMemo` will never trigger a render.

Having said that, the component will most likely re-render, because:

- You changed the values of `a` and `b` by updating the state. Calling the setter will trigger a component render.

  ```js
  // within your component
  setA(10); 
  setB(5);
  ```
- You changed the values of `a` and `b` by mutating the component props. Changing props will also trigger a component render.

  ```
  // inside parent component render
  <YourComponent a={10} b={5} />
  ```

So the change in `a` and/or `b` will already have triggered a render.

---

Your question is probably if `sum` will recompute during the render. To which the answer is **yes**. If `a` and/or `b` changes value the `useMemo` function is executed and the new value is calculated.

In your provided scenario `sum` is the result of a commutative operation. `a + b` produces the same result as `b + a`. However `useMemo` does not analyse the function passed and sees it as a black box. It does not know if the operation is commutative or not. Say you would have passed `a - b` instead, then swapping the `a` and `b` values produces a different value. Therefore `useMemo` has to recompute the result.

An easy way to test this would be to add a `console.log()` inside the `useMemo` call.

```js
let counter = 0;

function App() {
  const [a, setA] = React.useState( 5);
  const [b, setB] = React.useState(10);
  
  function swap() {
    setA(b);
    setB(a);
  }
  
  // const sum = React.useMemo(() => a + b, [a, b]);
  const sum = React.useMemo(() => {
    const result = a + b;
    console.log(`[${++counter}]`, "recomputing a + b =", result);
    return result;
  }, [a, b]);
  
  return (
    <div>
      <code>a = <input type="number" value={a} onChange={e => setA(+e.target.value)} /></code>
      <br />
      <code>b = <input type="number" value={b} onChange={e => setB(+e.target.value)} /></code>
      <br />
      <code>sum = {sum}</code>
      <br />
      <button type="button" onClick={swap}>swap</button>
    </div>
  );
}

ReactDOM.createRoot(document.querySelector("#root")).render(<App />);
```

```html
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react@18/umd/react.development.js"></script>
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@18/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>
<div id="root"></div>
```